# how to fade two images with ffmpeg

Tags: image, ffmpeg, transition, fade

I have two images and I want to create a simple fading transition between them.

I also want the final output to be a sequence of images rather than a video? 
So if the fading transition was 10 frames long I'd want the output to be a sequence of 10 images.

How can I achieve this with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See the [`blend` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blend):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input0.png -loop 1 -i input1.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3)))'" -t 4 frames_%04d.png
```

This example will make a 3 second cross-fade of `input1.png` over `input0.png`.

To crossfade/dip-to-black multiple images see [Create video with 5 images with fade-in/out effect in `ffmpeg`](https://superuser.com/a/834035/110524).

Comment: How to do the same effect for multiple images? Say I need to create a video with 3 images and need to apply this transition between the images

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/730062/ffmpeg-fade-between-images have posted a question regarding this.

Comment: Any ideas for fade out between multiple images?

Comment: error Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description making vedio from sequence of images any help pls

Answer (score -1):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot achieve this just with ffmpeg. Please take a look at [MLT framework](http://www.mltframework.org/) if you want to do it in scriprs; take a look at  openshot if you want an interactive app.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i input1.png \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i input2.png \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i input3.png \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i input4.png \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i input5.png \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3)))'[v0]; \
 [2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3)))'[v1]; \
 [3:v][2:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3)))'[v2]; \
 [4:v][3:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,3),1,T/3)))'[v3]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0[v]"
-map "[v]" out.mp4
```

Haven't tried with images, but you could try `-t 12 frames_%04d.png` at the end or whatever.