# ffmpeg- blend transition between images specified in a text file

Tags: ffmpeg

how can i create a blend transition effect between specified images? I have the file paths to images in a text file. My requirement is that i should be able to do a blend transition between specific images (whose path are in text file) for a specific duration.
I also have to annotate these images with text.For that i am using drawtext filter. The blend transition should be between annotated images.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fade two images with ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493797/how-to-fade-two-images-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The inputs here aren't explicit. To the OP, this could be done, but it would be tedious. You would have to know the time range of each image you wish to process and then use trim and pts filters to chop them off from the concatted input. It'd be much simpler to work with direct inputs to ffmpeg.

Comment: I have the sequence of images and time duration for which each image should be shown in the text file. I want to write text over a certain image,which i am able to do with drawtext filter, then i want to apply transition between specified frames, say between frame 10 and frame 11 for 3 seconds so that the annotated text appears smoothly in the final video.